# PHP get first child from div

Tags: php, domdocument

In below HTML Code, I want to get the content of `p tag`

### Example

```
<div class="body" style="text-align: justify;padding: 10px;">
   <p style="text-align: justify;" dir="RTL">
      ...............
   </p>

   TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST 
</div>
```

My current code is :

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($content);

echo $dom->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(0)->childNodes;
```

Why this code isn't correct and how to resolve this issue.

Comment: `…childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;`

Comment: @ElefantPhace thats not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting:

If you have this:

```
<?php
$content ='
<div class="body" style="text-align: justify;padding: 10px;">
    <p>this is a paragraph</p>
    TEST TEST TEST TEST 
</div>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($content);

$firstChildOfDiv = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0);
$value = $firstChildOfDiv->nodeValue;
echo "<PRE>",var_dump($value),"</PRE>";
```

Your output will be:

> `string(1) " "`

However, if you have this:

```
<?php
$content ='
<div class="body" style="text-align: justify;padding: 10px;"><p>this is a paragraph</p> TEST TEST TEST TEST </div>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($content);

$firstChildOfDiv = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0);
$value = $firstChildOfDiv->nodeValue;
echo "<PRE>",var_dump($value),"</PRE>";
```

Your output will be as expected:

```
 string(19) "this is a paragraph"
```

Seems like something weird is happening with the whitespace

Comment: Can i get child class value from div reference like <div class='main'><div id='test'>Test</div></div> extract 'test' by using both class as well as id

Comment: How Please can you tell me ?

Comment: If you ask a new specific question I will answer it if I see it

Comment: we are getting html content using jquery like jQuery('#id .main').text(); so it is reference so how to do using phpdom.

Comment: `childNodes->item(1)` should world in the first example. `childNodes->item(0)` references to the TextNode between div and p. The text content of the TextNode is the whitespace between the two.